# charts drawn using Chart.js are not captured, canvas issue?

Tags: android, screenshot, phonegap

Seems to be a problem with capturing canvas contents. My charts are not included in the screenshot image, and are blank. I am using Chart.js.

How can I capture the canvas content as well as other HTML contents?

Comment: can you elaborate on your question...from given information its hard to understand your probem

Comment: I need to capture the screenshot of screen that have HTML content and have graph view. I am showing graph with html attribute <canvas> and I am able to capture the screenshot of entire screen but the graph that I am showing using canvas is not capturing.

Comment: I am using the plugin https://github.com/gitawego/cordova-screenshot to capture the screenshot.